# Delphi recreate canvas

Tags: delphi, canvas

i am writing my own component that has its canvas. I made a procedure to  recreate the control's  canvas  :

```
procedure ClearCanvas;
 begin
 FreeAndNil(FCanvas);
 FCanvas := TControlCanvas.Create;
 TControlCanvas(FCanvas).Control := Self;
 end;
```

the newly created canvas works well , but the old canvas  is still showing its contents  !

any errors in the code ?!
Thanks

Comment: I can't make sense of this procedure. Simply calling `Invalidate` (or `Repaint`) method requests the control for repainting. The rendering itself is then done in the `Paint` method overridde.

Comment: Not an answer, but why on earth are you using `FreeAndNil`?

Comment: That's not how painting works. You only get a repaint when requested. The canvas does not retain any state. Repainting happens in paint cycle, in response to WM_PAINT. Almost certainly that code should be removed. It must be wrong.

Comment: Ofcourse the painting is done in Paint method. This ClearCanvas method is intended to "clear the canvas" as a preleminary for painting. Why not use FillRect ?! Because this will make the canvas opaque and i need to preserve transparency. So, the only solution i figured is to recreate the canvas of the component  to aquire a brand new transparent canvas, by using the TControlCanvas , which is very legitmate but trickey . All the three comnents above talk about the painting iteself , and the method in question is executed before the painting job being carried on .

Comment: There really is no transparency, it's a canvas - some sort of fabric. What gives the appearance of transparency is overlapping paintings. The only way to clear is to paint all to the background color. If you think your canvas looses it's transparency when you use FillRect, ask a question with a [mcve] that proves your point.

Comment: Dear Sertack ... we can discuss the issue of transperancy in differrent question , but in a few words : there is transperancy  , while not genuin . It is implemeneted using several techniques depending on the circumenstances , the most primitive of them is to fill with the background color, which is used when the component is placed in opaque unicolor parent. But is the parent has a gradient or wallpapered background , there will be no "background color" , and you will need more adavnced tehnique. The examples are lengthy so it may be difficult to post here , but you can google for "transparen

Comment: t controls" . The question per se is about the technique of recreating the control canvas, it is one of the most trickey and least documented of them , so i needed the help.

Comment: Recreating the canvas won't help you, it's not directly attached to device contexts, which are not directly attached to display surfaces anyway. You're on the wrong track.

Comment: BTW, however complex transparency is, it is achieved by painting over. No amount of that paint is actually transparent/translucent, the color that would give that appearance is calculated. In effect, there's not transparency.

Comment: Indeed the newly created canvas works well and draws fine , since it attaches to device context of the control via the last line before end , and becuse it is of type TControlCanvas  , not TCanvas. Indeed it the old canvas that behaves naughty : it is still visible though it is freed by FreeAndNil .

Comment: Yes ofcourse it is as you say, becuause the OS it self does not permit transparency except for the bare minimum , But we try to overcome the limitations :)

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and explain what you want to achieve and add a bit more context around your current code. Or delete your question completely because it is asking why X does not work and in reality in order to do what you want (achieve transparency) you would have to use Y.

Comment: No point asking if you ignore responses because you believe you know better. You don't. Until you can contemplate the fact that you don't understand why your code doesn't work, you are wasting everyone's time. Especially your own.

Comment: Dear David Heffernan and Dalija Prasnikar : i'm wondering about your offensive comments . The original question is very specific : how to recreate control's canvas. All relevant code is posted. Both of you are evaulating my approach and this is offtopic : the answer requested if you  want to give is how to make these 3 lines work. Thank you for your time and effort anyway.

Comment: I will edit the question any way to remove any possible ambiguity.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. That's the key point. Recreating the canvas does nothing useful. As you discovered. This was explained to you repeatedly. Eventually you accepted this.

Comment: So, @DavidHeffernan and I are offensive because we are trying to tell you that your approach is completely wrong. It is like asking why your car does not take you where you want to go and you forgot to mention you want to go to the Moon. You need a god damn rocket. And from your comments under accepted answer it is still clear that you will just try to build a better car. It will not work. So, if you want real answer to your problem, I suggest that you ask another question providing complete information about what you want to achieve and add more code to have [mcve] we can use.

Comment: I would also suggest that you Google it first, but with your misconceptions about Windows drawing system you will probably not get too far.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/313443)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no errors with the code you display, it successfully creates a control canvas that attaches to the control and gets rid of the old one.

The content you see does not get cleared when you free the canvas because it doesn't belong to the canvas. A VCL canvas is a class that ease working with graphic functions of the underlying OS. What gets drawn is ultimately on a device context retrieved for a window. If it's absolutely necessary to make an analogy with an actual canvas in your case, you have to get rid of the window of your control (or the window of its parent if it is a graphic control) to start with a *new* *canvas*.

What you have to actually do is to *erase* the contents. Erasing is not literal, it is in fact painting over with whatever background is considered to be the initial state.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer , I then should check Windows api reference to see if I can clear the device context, if not possible then I will be obliged to recreate it .

Comment: @DrWael - You're welcome. There's no API that *clears* a device context, what is generally used is filling with a solid color. Releasing, retrieving a device context won't help either, what gets drawn is to the window that the DC belongs to.

Comment: I was thinking that ResetDC might do the job , but no problem I may restructure my component guided by the behavior of the Clear button in the standard tpicture property editor .